# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having this problem in this component, this is the code:

```
const AuthLoading = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    AuthFlow();
  });

  const AuthFlow = () => {
    if (!props.triedJWT) {
      props.getUserToken();
      return;
    }

    if (!props.jwt) {
      props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
      return;
    }

    if (!props.triedLogIn) {
      props.getUserInfo();
      return;
    }

    if (!props.user) {
      props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
      return;
    }

    props.navigation.navigate('App');
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <LoadingScreen />
    </View>
  );
};
```

How can I fix this?

The `getUserInfo`and `getUserToken` are connected to Redux actions and modify the `jwt`, `triedJWF`, `triedLogin` and `user` props. So when they are called, they re render the component.

Maybe this isn't the best way to do it? To make the action change state props so when they re render the if conditions are different? I also want to know if this is common practice or not.

EDIT: This is the warning I'm getting:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting your error? In the redux update? If so, could you post some of that code? This code looks fine to me.

Comment: @ViktorW I added a screenshot, it's actually a warning not an error, but it says it might indicate a memory leak so I want to fix it.

Comment: Can you add an empty dependency array to `useEffect` and see if that changes anything? My guess is that your authFlow function is called multiple times even after it's not needed anymore.

Comment: At this current shape, your `useEffect` runs for every update. Have you tried to add a dependency array?

Comment: Which variable should I add to the dependency array?

Comment: I mean, I need the AuthFlow to run each update so that it can navigate to the right part accordingly

Comment: It should be [props.triedJWT, props.jwt, props.triedLogIn, props.user]> (those are all the dependencies in the callback) although I doubt that is the reason for the warning, but still, always good to have the dependency array.

Comment: I added them, it works but I still get the warning

Comment: I think the problem is not in this code. It might be the way you perform your redux updates, or on some other component. As I said, this code looks fine to me.

Comment: Redux updates just change the state that's passed as props in the mapStateToProps, what could be done wrong there?

Comment: Ok I added a setTimeout wrapping the navigate to auth lines and now it doesn't throw the warning, weird